# Pythonic way to split Filepath into Folder and Filename

Tags: python, split

I have a string as follows

```
file = 'C:/folder/subfolder/data.csv'
```

And I'm looking for a Pythonic way to split this string into 2 variables: **folder** and **name**

### Here is what I have so far

```
folder, name = '/'.join(file.split('/')[:-1]), file.split('/')[-1]
```

### Output

```
>>> folder
'C:/folder/subfolder'
>>> name
'data.csv'
```

But the code is not so good, I think, because I had to repeat `file.split('/')` twice.
Is there a more Pythonic way like a list comprehension to do this?

Comment: How about `folder, name = os.path.split(path)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern Python you should use pathlib:

```
file = pathlib.Path('C:/folder/subfolder/data.csv')
name = file.name
folder = str(file.parent)
```